# Thread identifier in multiprocessing pool workers

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I believed `Thread.ident` as a unique identifier of threads but now I see different worker processes in `multiprocessing.poo.Pool` reporting same thread identifier by `threading.current_thread().ident`.  How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the platform, the ids may or may not be unique. The important thing to note here is that the python multiprocessing library actually uses processes instead of threads for multiprocessing, and so thread ids in between processes is actually a platform-specific implementation detail.

On Unix/Linux: a thread id is guaranteed to be unique inside a single process. However, a thread id is not guaranteed to be unique across processes. The processid (pid), however, will be unique across processes. Thus, you can obtain a unique identifier by putting the two together. Detail from the `man pthread` page http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html

On windows: a thread id is unique across the whole machine: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686746(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @0x2c52 I had to search a bit for it, and in doing so, i'll clarify my answer. It looks like windows threads should be unique across the machine, while linux threads will be unique within the process. From man pthreads: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html -- "Thread IDs are guaranteed to be unique only within a process.  (In
       all pthreads functions that accept a thread ID as an argument, that
       ID by definition refers to a thread in the same process as the
       caller.)" Windows: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686746(v=vs.85).aspx