# Unique ID of current worker multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing

This is similar to an [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38949614/thread-identifier-in-multiprocessing-pool-workers), but applied to `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` instead of `multiprocessing.pool.Pool`. The accepted answer suggests thread ids should be unique per-process. Since my program is only using `ThreadPool`, I would expect `threading.current_thread().ident` to return something unique for each worker, but I am seeing multiple workers having the same ID concurrently.

Do `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` workers correspond to one thread? Is there a way to get a unique worker ID for each of the workers launched by a `tpool().map(...)` invocation?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38949614/thread-identifier-in-multiprocessing-pool-workers?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I did reference the other question explicitly, and I did try to clarify that this is dealing with with `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`, not `multiprocessing.pool.Pool`.

Comment: However, because of the mistake made by the OP of question 38949614, where they use thread identifiers instead of `(thread_id, pid)`, in addition to another mistake that I made, the same solution applies to this question, namely `thread_id`. My premise was wrong and indeed each `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` worker does seem to map to a unique thread ID obtained via `threading.current_thread().ident`. 

However, I still don't think the question is a duplicate.